# How to break one variable in two?

Tags: java, regex, variables

I have a string variable with a space separating an email address and a password.  For example:

```
one_variable="foo@yahoo.com password"
```

I would like to separate the email address from the password and create two strings from it, like this:

```
email_variable="foo@yahoo.com"
password_variable="password"
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Simply split by `space`

Comment: Sorry, But i don't get you .. Can you please help me?

Comment: [Read this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/3150943)

Comment: `String parts[]=one_variable.split(" ");` and then access the array with indices to get the variables

Comment: Use [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
String one_variable="foo@yahoo.com password";
String tok[]=one_variable.split(" ");
System.out.println(tok[0]);
System.out.println(tok[1]);
```

Code basically would spilt the string from space.
If in case you have multiple spaces use `\\s+` to spilt i.e `one_variable.split("\\s+")`.
**Output :**

```
foo@yahoo.com
password
```

Comment: Please wait sir.. I'll aceept your answer after checking this program..

Comment: You might want to change it to `\\s+` to handle *multiple spaces* as well.